# Keyboard on Surface Laptop does not work

Tags: surface-tablet, release-hera

Everything looks goods on new elementary OS (v5.1) on my Surface Laptop. But facing issue with laptop's keyboard, It does not work (everything fine on external keyboard). Any one can support this?

regards
Alessio

Answer (score 0):

I found this and maybe this Github project help you : https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface

Comment: Dec 2019 Microsoft Surface Laptop 3, i5 1035G7 8GB, 256GB SSD, Windows 10 1909 and with Elementary OS the keyboard and trackpad don't work. I'm also pretty new at all this and the https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface isn't that clear to me. So some very simple instructions would be great, and without a keyboard how does one input the commands?? Plus is it likely to work on a Laptop 3.

Answer (score 0):

As per the feature matrix in the linux-surface repo, the keyboard should work if you install the linux-surface kernel.

Follow these steps:
https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup#surface-kernel-installation